# Почему вставляется некорректно результат поиска по базе?

Tags: php

```
<option value="с.Завгороднє" (Петрівська="" сільрада)="">с.Завгороднє (Петрівська сільрада)</option>
```

А должно вставиться все :

```
  echo "<br>";
    echo "<select id='selectTowns' >";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "<option value=".$row['ter_name'].">".$row['ter_name']."</option>";
    } ;
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Это точно тот код для вывода?

Comment: получилось, что для `value` кавычек не вывели

Comment: точно большое спасибо!!

Comment: Экранировать лучше тоже не забывать, а то мало ли где и как XSS найдут

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При выводе преобразуйте специальные символы (кавычки тоже) в HTML-сущности и кавычки экранируйте в строке, например так:

```
$ter = htmlspecialchars($row['ter_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo "<option value=\"{$ter}\">{$ter}</option>";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<br>';
echo '<select id="selectTowns">';
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   echo '<option value="'.$row['ter_name'].'">'.$row['ter_name'].'</option>';
} ;
echo '</select>';
echo '<br>';
```